# How to return data from azure databricks notebook in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, azure-databricks

I have a requirement where I need to transform data in azure databricks and then return the transformed data. Below is notebook sample code where I am trying to return some json.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import json
import pandas as pd



# Define a dictionary containing ICC rankings
rankings = {'test': ['India', 'South Africa', 'England',
                            'New Zealand', 'Australia'],
              'odi': ['England', 'India', 'New Zealand',
                            'South Africa', 'Pakistan'],
               't20': ['Pakistan', 'India', 'Australia',
                              'England', 'New Zealand']}
   
# Convert the dictionary into DataFrame
rankings_pd = pd.DataFrame(rankings)
   
# Before renaming the columns
   
rankings_pd.rename(columns = {'test':'TEST'}, inplace = True)
rankings_pd.rename(columns = {'odi':'ODI'}, inplace = True)
rankings_pd.rename(columns = {'t20':'twenty-20'}, inplace = True)  
# After renaming the columns
#print(rankings_pd.to_json())
dbutils.notebook.exit(rankings_pd.to_json())
```

In order to achieve the same, I created a job under a cluster for this notebook and then I had to create a custom connector too following this article https://medium.com/@poojaanilshinde/create-azure-logic-apps-custom-connector-for-azure-databricks-e51f4524ab27. Using the connectors with API endpoint **'/2.1/jobs/run-now'** and then **'/2.1/jobs/runs/get-output'** in Azure Logic App, I am able to get the return value but after the job is executed successfully, sometimes I just get the status as running with no output. I need to get the output when job is executed successfully with transformation.
Please suggest a way better way for this if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 1):

looks like dbutils.notebooks.exit() only accpet "string", you can return the value as json string and convert to json object in DataFactory or Logic App. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils#--notebook-utility-dbutilsnotebook